# Dockerfile with dependency projects

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a solution with 4 projects. The structure is as follows:

> 1) Project1
>
> 2) Project2
>
> 3) Project3
>
> 4) Project4

`Project1` and `Project2` are executable projects and both of them use `Project3` and `Project4` as dependency projects which are not executable.

> How should I make my dockerfile so I can copy for example `Project2` to the container but in a way where `Project3` and `Project4` would still be recognized by a container, so `Project2` could build its dependency projects?

Same rule goes for `Project1`. `Project1` and `Project2` are not connected. They should be in separated containers.

I was trying to use `VOLUME` in order to share the solution directory with a host, but I have read that `VOLUME` does not communicate with the host. It only creates volumes on container.

I am using .NET Core 2.1 for all of the projects.

I would appreciate if someone could suggest how I should approach my problem.

Comment: in Dockerfile in project1 you can do `COPY ../Project3 /Project3`... or is that to mainstream for you?

Comment: The thing is that if I want to maintain clean structure I can't do ../Project3 cause I am getting error that it can't copy something from outbound of the context. Which is...stupid. I don't know why docker should care if I am saying "../". Docker is forcing me to stay in that "main" directory and copy stuff that are part of it. If I want to copy only specific projects I should place all dockerfile-s in the solution directory and not project specific directory, which I want to avoid. In this case it would be only 2 dockerfiles but in the future it could be much more.